# Store Table in Java Object - Datastructure

Tags: java, object, data-structures

I have to store data structured as a table in JAVA. Besides the columnnames and data i store different metadata like the data type of the column. At the moment I'm using this object.

```
public class Data {

    private final Map<String, List<Object>> values;
    private final Map<String, Integer> columnSpec;
    private int rowSize;

    //Getter and Setter
```

As you can see I save the data columnoriented. Sometimes I have to itterate over data in specific column. Sometimes over specific rows. I'm looking for a structre where i can easily switch from column to row layout (or vice versa).

Which object do you suggest? How can i reach the maximum performance (less iteration to change layout)? The table can have over 1 Million lines in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a library is not a problem, you can use Guava table structures. Some of the avaliable structures are: [TreeBasedTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html), [HashBasedTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html), [ImmutableTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.html) and [ArrayTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html). You can pick the most suitable one.

Comment: Thanks guava was exactly what i was looking for. This reduced my code enormously.